# Msal logout method sign out user before selecting account from popup

Tags: azure, office-js, azure-ad-msal, outlook-web-addins, msal.js

I would logout current user with msal library

I'm using `UnauthenticatedTemplate` to show signin page (App component is the signin page )

```
<UnauthenticatedTemplate>
  <App title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
</UnauthenticatedTemplate>
<AuthenticatedTemplate>
  <HashRouter>
    <Route
      render={({ location }) => (
        <>
          {location.pathname === "/" && <ToolbarComp />}
          <Switch>
          ....routes
          </Switch>
        </>
      )}
    />
  </HashRouter>
</AuthenticatedTemplate>
```

here's the sign out function

```
export const logout = async (msalInstance: PublicClientApplication, browserHistory: any) => {
  try {
    await msalInstance.logoutPopup();
    browserHistory.push("/");
    console.log("logout ok");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

[image]

When I click on log out button and run the function. The popup opens to choose signout account. But my app renders `UnauthenticatedTemplate` component before I choose account

[image]

What I expect is that the `UnauthenticatedTemplate` renders after choosing the account to disconnect. Or disconnect the current account then redirect. But not disconnect before I select account

Comment: Hi @infodev, what platform are you seeing this behavior with?

Comment: I'm using outlook macos